# mapbox weird behavior in chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, webkit, css-transitions

I have an ordered list that each have a number on them like so:

[image: list]
<sub>(source: [red-team-design.com](http://red-team-design.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/css3-ordered-list-styles.png))</sub>

the circles with numbers have "position:relative" so I can set their z-index. Under the ordered list I have a mapbox map. The page renders correctly until I zoom in or out on the map. When I do this, the relative elements in the list items act strange. The numbers in the right column are moved to under the numbers on the left column for a split second then move back. As far as I can tell, this only happens because the class ".leaflet-zoom-anim" is added to my map, then taken off. That css class looks like the following:

```
.leaflet-pan-anim .leaflet-tile,.leaflet-touching .leaflet-zoom-animated,.leaflet-zoom-anim .leaflet-tile {
    -webkit-transition: none;
    -moz-transition: none;
    -o-transition: none;
    transition: none;
}
```

Note that this weird behavior does not occur in safari or firefox.

EDIT: this only happens when the number has "position:relative" and if I add an image next to it with "position:relative" it has the same weird behavior

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution myself. This seems to be a problem with my version of Chrome(35.0.1916.114). I fixed the issue by adding -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px); to the div element containing the map